# Get all textboxes' values in a form in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a form tha contains a TreeView with many Textboxes in each node. the TreeView created dynamically with Razor and I don't know the name or ID of textboxes. 
How can I get the value and id of all textboxes in the controller in MVC3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the `FormCollection` class. Read about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx

In your controller;

```
Public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection formCollection){
}
```

This allows you to gain access to any of the keys posted.

Comment: This is a better (less leaky) way to do it than Request.Form, but either will work.

Answer (score 2):

`Request.Form.AllKeys` will allow you to access all the fields in the form's ids.  Then you can use `Request.Form[id]` to access the value.

Edit: Possible Dupe:[How can I get all element values from Request.Form without specifying exactly which one with .GetValues(“ElementIdName”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159103/)

Comment: could you please write a sample code. and How can I detect Textboxes in AllKeys

Comment: @Mohammad You want him to give you sample code, yet you provided absolutely nothing with respect to code in your question?

Comment: really?  It's pretty simple code...   `public void SomeAction() { foreach(var id in Request.Form.Keys){ Trace.WriteLine("Name: " + id + " Value: " + Request.Form[id]);}}`